# Why sharing session to implement SSO is not good?

Tags: session, single-sign-on, cas

Why sharing session to implement SSO is not good? I'm learning SSO system.

**Thinking about this scenes:**
Assume that all http requests to business services is required Login, the business services need verify the requests is login or not by asking SSO service in CAS or SAML. If there are 10 business services, and each service's request is `1k req/s`, so the SSO service's request is `10k req/s`. It's hard to image the SSO service can hold on.

SO, may be there is a cache mechanism in the business services to verify login token. But when user logout, the SSO service need remove the verify info, and the business services need remove the cache verify info also. I think that's too complicated. The SSO service need tell the business services some people was logout. So why don't all service sharing the **login token verify info**? Let SSO service write, and other business read. It remind me the `sharing the session to implement SSO`. And I thought if I can sharing the **login token verify info** by **redis distributed cluster**. But I have hear sharing session is not good? So why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether the SSO server can handle that many requests depends on your deployment of it. There are very large deployments of CAS that handle hundreds of thousands of requests. It varies.

In general, the SSO session is entirely separate from your application session. Once you have logged onto the application via SSO, you have established a session for that application that will last for as long as you configure it to last. When it expires, your application may decide to authenticate against your SSO server again. If the SSO server has still an SSO session, it will simply re-issue the appropriate data and your app will recreate the session. If not, it will challenge the user for credentials, whatever they may, and redo the same.

Session concerns of the application are entirely yours and application's concerns. The SSO server should never get involved. If your application has a requirement to share sessions because it's clustered, then you should share sessions. Nobody said it's a bad idea. However, you generally want to make sure your application is as stateless as possible since that will make clustered deployments easier.

When you log out from your application, your app session is gone, but the SSO session may still exist. As a result, you will get right back into the app because there is no need to provide credentials. If you wish, you could log out of the app AND your SSO server.

If you have all other applications logged in via SSO, and you wish to log out of all by logging out of one, this is called SLO. Your SSO server will need to reach out to every app that it has created a ticket for and contact them to logout. Or, you could destroy the shared sessions for all apps assuming they are all part of the same suite.